# No result after trying to run local function C#

Tags: c#

I'm completely new to C# and I'm trying to write a function that calculates when a certain amount has doubled (in *n* number of years) following compound interest rates.

Now, when I run this in VS Code, I don't receive any errors but I'm not getting a result either. This is my code so far:

```
using System;

int NumberOfYearsToDouble(int Amount, int InterestRate) {
    int NumberOfYears = 0;
    int Percentage;

    while (Amount < (Amount*2)) {
        Percentage = (Amount/100) * InterestRate;
        Amount = Amount + Percentage;
        NumberOfYears++;
    }
    return NumberOfYears;
}
NumberOfYearsToDouble(1000,8);
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: I bet the code execution doesn't stop either. Your `while` condition can't ever return `false`.

Comment: Return != Print to console. Return = return this value to the method that called me. So you're returning the result, but discarding it by not assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Beceause, you are not printing anything. try **Console.WriteLine(NumberOfYearsToDouble(1000,8));**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not printed your result in the console. And also your while loop is always true, you have an infinite loop.
Try this and you will see result in your console :

```
    using System;

    int NumberOfYearsToDouble(int Amount, int InterestRate) {
        int NumberOfYears = 0;
        int Percentage;
        condition = Amount*2

        while (Amount < condition) {
            Percentage = (Amount/100) * InterestRate;
            Amount = Amount + Percentage;
            NumberOfYears++;
        }
        return NumberOfYears;
    }
    int results = NumberOfYearsToDouble(1000,8);
    Console.WriteLine(results);
```

Please, take a look in your loop condition to see clearly and make sure to print result in the console to see result. It will help you for debugin purpose. Thanks

Comment: `condition = Amount*2` won't compile

Answer (score 3):

You're creating an infinite loop:

```
while (Amount < (Amount*2))
```

`Amount` will always be less than `Amount*2`, (unless `Amount` is a negative integer).

You should store the value of `Amount*2` before your `while` loop, so that it remains constant as `Amount` changes:

```
int doubleAmount = Amount*2;
while (Amount < doubleAmount)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I only realized my mistake just now, so stupid :( Anyway, it works now, so thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

you should try to fix it like this

```
int result = NumberOfYearsToDouble(1000,8);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```